# final var changes value JAVA

Tags: java, swing, final

I dont understand why i have initialized HEIGHT and WEIGHT as 32 and it's ok in Window(), but in inner class GamePanel it has value 1 and 2, btw SCALE is 20 as in Window()

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
    private final int SCALE;
    private final int WIDTH;
    private final int HEIGHT;

    public Window()
    {
        super("Snake");
        SCALE=20;
        WIDTH=32;
        HEIGHT=32;
        setSize(new Dimension(SCALE*WIDTH,SCALE*HEIGHT));
        setLocation(getWidth()/2,0);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        setContentPane(gamePanel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class GamePanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
            drawGrid(g);
            System.out.println(SCALE);
            System.out.println(WIDTH);
            System.out.println(HEIGHT);
        }

        public void drawGrid(Graphics g)
        {
            //
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Console:
20
1
2

Comment: Are you sure that you are indeed printing the `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` variables you initialized above? Maybe the `JPanel` has variables with the same name and you are printing them. Not sure though. You could test it by renaming the variables to something uncommon.

Comment: Get an IDE and then follow both variables to see what they ___really___ are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WIDTH and HEIGHT variables do not belong to your Window class. They are from java.awt.Image.ImageObserver interface.

Here is the content of the interface I mentioned

```
package java.awt.image;

import java.awt.Image;

public interface ImageObserver {

    public static final int WIDTH = 1;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 2;
    public static final int PROPERTIES = 4;
    public static final int SOMEBITS = 8;
    public static final int FRAMEBITS = 16;
    public static final int ALLBITS = 32;
    public static final int ERROR = 64;
    public static final int ABORT = 128;

    public boolean imageUpdate(Image image, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When do you:
private class GamePanel extends JPanel

You are extending JPanel so you inherit all its public/protected/package variables as well. If you check all inheritance tree:

JPanel <- JComponent <- Container <- Component <- ImageObserver

If you check ImageObserver source you will find:

```
public static final int WIDTH = 1;
public static final int HEIGHT = 2;
```

Since variables over inheritance are taken in priority of outer class. thats the value shown.

So consider pass them as parameters to have the right value.